# get avatar from facebook graph

Tags: facebook, avatar

I use this plugin to get fb connect

wordpress.org/plugins/nextend-facebook-connect/

the problem is I need to show avatar from FB graph that stored on database. when I use this plugin wordpress.org/plugins/sidebar-login/ this plugin can show the fb avatar perfectly. now I just need to create some coding that can call that avatar image.

when I use this:
get_avatar is show misterius man avatar, not fb why, my question is sidebar-login plugin can show the fb gtaph avatar use same tag "get_avatar"

```
get_avatar( $this->user->ID, apply_filters( 'sidebar_login_widget_avatar_size', 38 ) )
```

this is confusing me, sorry please help

Note: i need show avatar in content page but I show that use custom template page with php code. thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution!

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
echo get_avatar( $current_user->ID, 48 );
```